# How to find the duration of stay in Singapore for Pakistani passport?

Tags: visas, singapore

I am Pakistani national holding Pakistani passport. I am planning to apply for the Singapore Tourist Visa at the Singapore Consulate Karachi. The visa provide by Singapore consulate is almost similar to [image]

In this visa, it is mentioned around 35 days, so my query is, does my duration of stay in Singapore is 35 days or somewhere else on Google I read that, Immigration Councillor at Singapore has the right to provide me either 35 days or less.

Comment: ok if the visa is for 30 days and its double entry so what is (double entry means ) can a person after his first month go out and come back to have another month ? or the double entry is within the 1 month that the person get in the Embankment or stamped on the passport ?

Comment: @maher - I converted your answer to a comment, as you clearly weren't answering the question.  I suggest you click "Ask Question" at top right, as people are far more likely to see it then and help you out! :)

Comment: @maher A/c to my information, you've only 30 days maximum to re-enter again. What I mean to say is, let suppose you entered on 1st Sept 2012 and Immigration officers granted you 30 days, then from 1st sept to 30 sept, you can re-enter into Singapore. But, you can stay in Singapore till 30 Sept, not any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I applied for 'Tourist Visa' of Singapore. The visa stamped from Singapore Consulate, Karachi is much similar to the image above, only the difference is of 'Type of Visa'. In my case, Type of Visa = DOUBLE JOURNEY. Every tourist visitor needs to fill the 'Embarkment Form' which is available at Singapore Airport and collected by Immigration Officer. In the Embarkment Form, they ask about how much duration of stay you required in Singapore either 14 days or 30 days, so I selected the 30 days. The immigration officer granted 30 days without asking even a single question.

After that a higher ranking immigration officer asked a few question from me; reason for these questions might have been my nationality and my physical appearance (keeping heavy beard). Anyway, the questions were:

1. Where do you stay? (I already have a CONFIRMED booking of a hotel for 2 days)
2. Do you have return ticket to your country? (I have a CONFIRMED return ticket from Kuala Lumpur to Karachi and already have Malaysia tourist visa too).
3. What is the purpose of visit in Singapore? (Tourism + job hunting. BTW, he didn't show any concerns when I told him about job hunting on Tourist visa, so I feel Singapore give leverage on it)
4. Any company or recruitment agency contacted you? (Yes, I showed the print out of emails)
5. Any relative or friend in Singapore? (Friend, keep his contact number, officer will ask for it)
6. What encourage you to do job hunt in Singapore (IT market is awesome in Asia, life standard is good, another interested to continue my education in Singapore)

Answer (score 5):

The eligibility requirements and process for obtaining a tourist visa to Singapore are available on Singapore's [Immigration and Checkpoints Authority web site](http://www.ica.gov.sg/). They list Pakistan as a [Level II Assessment country](http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=169&secid=166) and require visitors from Pakistan to complete [form 14A](http://www.ica.gov.sg/data/resources/docs/Visitor%20Services/Form%2014A.pdf). This form asks the intended length of stay and the visa is likely to be issued accordingly.

While not stated on the ICA site, [tourism](http://articles.desi.net/singapore-tourist-visa-guidelines-for-indians/) [sites](http://singapore.tourism-asia.net/singapore-visa-rules.html) indicate that a Singapore tourist visa can initially be issued for up to 30 days. However, if no time period is indicated on the application form, the visa will be issued for 14 days. A social visa (for visiting family/friends) may allow a longer initial period. Once in Singapore, the visa [can be extended](http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=101&secid=100) one time for up to a total of 90 days from first entry.

Comment: @g . After reviewing the form 14A, it is clear that the applicant have to mention the duration of stay as this question is marked as necessary. So, there is no question of 'Not mentioning' duration of stay. Anyways, I will go through process and update this thread as I got the visa stamp.